# google spread sheet で作ったマクロスクリプトを他のシートでも使いたい

Tags: google-spreadsheet

google spread sheet で作ったマクロスクリプトを他のシートでも使いたいです。
いまは、既存のマクロを適用するときは、あらかじめスクリプトをクリップボードにコピーしておいて、ほかのスプレッドシートを開き、適当なマクロを記録して、編集してペーストで上書きして使っていますが、非常に手間です。

なにかスマートな方法はないでしょうか？